# How to create images in PHP

Tags: php, image

Is it possible to create images with PHP (as opposed to simply linking to them via HTML) and if so, where should I go first to learn about such a thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prefer the [GD library](http://www.php.net/gd) - check out [the Examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples.php), and this example:

```
<?php
header ("Content-type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
      or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Outputs:

[image: imagecreatetrucolor example]
<sub>(source: [php.net](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/figures/image.imagecreatetruecolor.png))</sub>

See [imagecreatetruecolor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php).

Comment: You should always try to use the header() function at the last moment possible (such as, before the imagepng() funciton).  The way it is now, if the php script dies "Cannot Initialize new GD image stream" the browser will try to interpret it as a gif, so it won't be intelligible.

Answer (score 6):

Yes this is possible. I believe there are multiple libraries to accomplish this. The most widely used is probably [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) which is actually not PHP specific but comes with appropriate bindings.

See also in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/imagick).

Answer (score 3):

Check out [GD](https://www.php.net/gd).  It contains a ton of functions for image creation,manipulation and interrogation. Your PHP install just has to built with the GD library which it probably was.

Answer (score 3):

For decent tutorials on image generation using PHP:

GD - http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/1269

ImageMagick - http://www.sitepoint.com/article/dynamic-images-imagemagick

Answer (score 1):

[PHP GD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.image.php)

[Pear Image_Canvas](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_Canvas) (and [Image_Graph](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_Graph) for graphs)

Those are the two I know of.

Answer (score 0):

MagickWand is pretty good for that as well, and pretty powerful.

http://www.bitweaver.org/doc/magickwand/index.html

This snippet will take an image, wrie the 'rose' in Vera, or whatever fonts are available, and flush the image to the browser.

```
$drawing_wand=NewDrawingWand();
DrawSetFont($drawing_wand,"/usr/share/fonts/bitstream-vera/Vera.ttf");
DrawSetFontSize($drawing_wand,20);
DrawSetGravity($drawing_wand,MW_CenterGravity);
$pixel_wand=NewPixelWand();
PixelSetColor($pixel_wand,"white");
DrawSetFillColor($drawing_wand,$pixel_wand);
if (MagickAnnotateImage($magick_wand,$drawing_wand,0,0,0,"Rose") != 0) {
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
MagickEchoImageBlob( $magick_wand );
} else {
echo MagickGetExceptionString($magick_wand);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use gd library with different function of it.
and create good image with the code

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");

//try to create an image
$im = @imagecreate(800, 600)
or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");

//set the background color of the image
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xDD);

//set the color for the text 
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 133, 14, 91);

//adf the string to the image
imagestring($im, 5, 300, 300,  "I'm a pretty picture:))", $text_color);

//outputs the image as png
imagepng($im);

//frees any memory associated with the image 
imagedestroy($im);
```

color to Negative

```
if(!file_exists('dw-negative.png')) {
    $img = imagecreatefrompng('dw-manipulate-me.png');
    imagefilter($img,IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
    imagepng($img,'db-negative.png');
    imagedestroy($img);
}
```